# Get your website classified as 'first-party' in Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, cookies, safari

I'm running into a major issue with Safari compatibility for my website. It's not an error per say, but apparently Safari classifies my website as 'third party'.

This means, that for me to set cookies (which is 100% necessary for my web app to run), the user needs to open up Safari preferences, click to 'Privacy' and opt-out of Safari's default setting. They need to set Safari's cookie policy from 'Block cookies from third parties' to 'Never block cookies'.

This is a terrible experience and means that probably most users who use Safari on my site will just navigate away because it's not working. I could pop up an info graphic to walk the user through the process, but come on... Most every other major browser (chrome, firefox, etc) takes an opposite stance and default to accepting all cookies.

Is there some application process to Apple that will get my website classified as 'first party'? Does it have something to do with SSL? Is it a CORS issue?

How do I get classified as a 'first party' website?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a conceptual misunderstanding here. A web site isn't first-party or third-party by itself, and there isn't some kind of list of these maintained by Apple. It is the third party in a specific context. When Safari blocks third-party cookies, what that means is that website www.aaa.com (the site the user is visiting) can't set (or retrieve) a cookie for www.bbb.com (a third party to the transaction between the user and www.aaa.com). I suspect you are doing something involving an iframe or otherwise including elements from one domain in a web page on another domain, and that is the source of the problem.